# checking if fixture is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have fixture and test class defined the like the below. However the test is failing stating env variable is not found. How can I check if the test fixture is executed and env variable is set?

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('env', 'dev')
```

**Test Module**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'source')))
from engine import get_client_id

def test_get_client_id():
    get_client_id()
```

Comment: Show the `get_client_id` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a test for it to check that the environment variable is set. This test passes for me:

test_env_is_set.py:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'source')))


def test_env_is_set():
    assert os.environ.get('env') == 'dev'
```

Comment: Thank you , this helped to drill down on the issue.